# Body height and horizontal scrolling with html/css

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to make a website with one background image that is moving horizontally while scrolling.
I have the scrolling done okay but I have problems adjusting the body size so that it always is fitted to my image (no splicing of the image or no white background after image), no matter the size of my browser's window.

I have achieved scrolling with jquery and tried to play with `body`/`section` `height`s/`width`s in my css with no success...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/05/00/34/panorama-2117310_960_720.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>website.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section></section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
      $('section').css({
        'background-position-x': -scroll_position,
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The image can be found at: https://pixabay.com/photos/panorama-miami-florida-water-usa-2117310/

As you can hopefully see, depending on whether you are in full screen or not, it will slice the picture (for me, using body `height: 200vh`) or add white background after the picture (`300vh`). 
I would like, if possible, to have the page always stop at the end of the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that you need to consider is the screen ratio so the horizontal and vertical scroll are different and the initial view (the `viewport`) different.

The calculation will be getting the **ratio** of the `scrollTop` (only, that's why we subtract the window's height) relatively the full height and in the same ratio we'll scroll the section horizontally (again, subtract the window's width)

I hope it's not too much complicated.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const ratio = ($(window).scrollTop() / ($('body').height() - $(window).height()));
  var scroll_position = ratio * ($('section').width() - $(window).width());
  $('section').css({
    'background-position-x': -scroll_position,
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --viewport: 200vh;
}

body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  body {
    height: var(--viewport);
  }
  
  section
  {
    width: var(--viewport);
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/05/00/34/panorama-2117310_960_720.jpg);
    background-size: var(--viewport) 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
  }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  section
  {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/05/00/34/panorama-2117310_960_720.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<section></section>
```

https://jsbin.com/gabugeg/3/edit?html,css,output

I used the `--viewport: 200vh;` variable just to make it easier to change in multiple places at once.

The code can be written in more optimised way but I wanted the code to be more readable.

Let me know if everything is clear.

**Update**

To support weird screen ratios (width / height = 2 in this example) you can use the media queries `(min-aspect-ratio)` and `(max-aspect-ratio: 2/1)`. If you use different image with different dimensions, you probably will need to tune it again.

Comment: That definitely works perfectly. I may have started with too big a project to learn these languages (especially javascript); I will take the time to understand your answer this week end (this is a hobby project).

Comment: Glad to hear :) If you need more help with the learning process (I'm a mentor at codingcoach), find my details in my profile page..

Comment: I have just realised that when the image is at its smallest size (small browser window), you can then see the white background again. Is there a way to never get this white background? Maybe add a minimum size for the background image?